# How to access custom columns in a sharepoint library - graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am listing the children in the root of a document library with custom columns. When I make the following call with the MS graph REST API, no custom column data is returned for the child items.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/<site-id>/drive/root/children`

I have tried using `?expand=...` without success. Is this possible with either the v1 or beta endpoints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Endpoint `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/<site-id>/drive/root/children` returns the collection of *files metadata* ([`DriveItem` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0)) in the root of the drive.

The associated document library list items could be retrieved via [`DriveItem.listItem` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) including the values of the columns set on this list item (via [`ListItem.fields` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/listitem?view=graph-rest-1.0)) like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/root/children?$expand=listItem($expand=fields)
```

Alternatively, SharePoint Library list items and column values (including custom ones) could be retrieved instead:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/list/items?$expand=fields
```

or list items along with files metadata:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drive/list/items?$expand=fields,driveItem
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me understand how I could have figured this out from the documentation? I felt it wasn't clear.

Comment: Basically, [Relationships properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) contains the list of all the associated entities that could be retrieved along with DriveItem resource

Comment: I see. Thanks again!